# Inserting a has many relationship tables at the same time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using PHP Laravel Framework.I have 1 to M relationship tables `order` and `products`.

`ORDER TABLE  - orderid <--autoincrement primary key`  
                          `- orderdate`  
                          `- Name`

`PRODUCTS TABLE  - productid <--autoincrement primary key` 
                              `- orderid <--foreign key reference to order table`  
                              `- productName`
                              `- price`
My models are as below --> 
**Order Model :**

```
class Order extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $table = 'order';

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Products','orderid');
    }

}
```

**Products Model :**

```
class Products extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'products';
}
```

I have a form where I am taking the order date,name of the customer and the products details that can be more than one products.User can have one or many products in one order.
So now i have to insert details about both the tables in one go .
I read this doc http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models 
they have given this below code for inserting related models -->

```
$comments = array(
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A new comment.')),
    new Comment(array('message' => 'Another comment.')),
    new Comment(array('message' => 'The latest comment.'))
);

$post = Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

But here they know the id to find from the parent table but in my case I have to insert details in the Order table and then the details about the products in the Products table for the order which was inserted just before . **Problem is how to find the newly inserted orderid** ? I am using autoincrement for `orderid` field in the Order table.

Comment: i don't really see the connection between your posts--comments and orders--products.

Comment: that is just the example from the documentation just for those who didn't visit the link :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply:

```
$order = new Order;
... // assign some properties
$order->save();

$products = [new Product(...), new Product(...)];

$order->products()->saveMany($products);
```

And set the `protected $primaryKey` on the models, like Zwacky already said.

Now, I doubt it's the relation you want. That means every product exists only in the context of a single order. I think this should be many to many, but that's your call.

Comment: Yah **mass assignment** worked just had to add fillable fields inside child table model . But didn't understand why M to M can u elaborate a lil more ?

Comment: could you check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500198/laravel-which-route-or-link-should-i-use-for-this-case

Comment: @VishalNair Do you want to  create a product for every order you get? I would guess not. Instead you would have (basic setup) a table with products, a table with orders, and a pivot table to link products to the orders.

Comment: So laravel/eloquent requires you to add the parent first, and then manually add the children? The object tree can't be persisted in a single invocation?

Comment: @EnmanuelRivera you can use `push()` on the parent model, it will save it and all its relations that you assigned to the instance. However, there is no unit-of-work-ish way in bare eloquent, instead you'd create your implementation in eg. repository

Answer (score 1):

if you create model by model you shouldn't have any problems. if you `save()` the model, its primary key `id` property will be set with the last inserted id automatically. here some idea:

```
$products = [];
foreach (['product A', 'product B'] as $name) {
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $name;
    $product->price = 15;
    $product->save();
    // $product->id will be set after save()
    array_push($products, $product);
}

$someOrder->products()->saveMany($products);
```

Comment: didn't worked . BTW why are we passing an empty array $products inside saveMany ?

Comment: don't take the code literally (corrected it, to add the products to the `$products` array). it's just to show, that after you `save()` you'll have the `id`s set, without having to use `Product::find(1)->id`.

Comment: Have you tested this because when i am trying, it is throwing me an error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'orderid' doesn't have a default value` which means its not getting the orderid foreign key value automatically.I tried your updated code also.

Comment: i assume you've set the right primary key in your models, since it differs from the default (`id`) one.

Comment: check I have updated the Order Model code (added the second parameter to `hasMany()` which specifies on which column the relationship is made ) yet not working.

Comment: since your `Products` model uses another primary key as the default one (id) you need to set that `protected $primaryKey = 'productid';` within the model.

Comment: No still not working tried it with specifying the correct id also . I think **mass assignment** is the answer .