# laravel which route or link should I use for this case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have an `xmldocument` model, which I can show its profile in this way:

```
`public/xmldocument/4`
```

From this page, there are three links, which are:

```
add general information 

add master information

add general information
```

each of them is for a resource. for example:

add general information is the create of the resource `general_information`

add master information is the create of the resource `master_information`

add general information is the create of the resource `general_information`

But each of them must know the xmldocument id. in my case, each of them should know that they are belongs to the `xmldocument = 4`

My question is should I route each of them to this link

```
`public/xmldocument/4/generalinformation/create` ?
```

or to this link

```
`public/generalinformation/create` ?
```

in the second case, I have to pass the xmldocument id, but can I really do that using the `a` tag?

Comment: I would appreciate the guy how downvote the question to write why did he/she did that

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If your business logic consists of nested models, then you should be using the former route schema, otherwise, you can use the latter schema and try to store the `xmldocument` in session

Comment: Depends on your app. Probably 1st approach is the way to go for you, but mind that you need to secure this kind of routes. 2nd approach doesn't let you pass 'parent' `id` in the url, so you would need to append it to the form for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as **Oni** said, its something related to your business logic, so there are no way as the best way or a way which is better than this way, its all back to you ..

now about the second question sending the id of the document when using

```
public/generalinformation/create
```

in general you should append the `id` of the document to the link so that you can handle it in the next page as `a` tag will only provide `_GET` values, but in Laravel you can use `slug` for example to solve this issue so your link can be something like

```
public/xml_doc_slug/generalinformation/create
```

so this way you query your database for the `slug` and get the `id` of the xml document.

In my opinion, try to make your URL's as simple as you can so that you can deal with it later.